# php prepared statement Update - sets wrong value

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to make an update with a prepared statement, but it keeps updating the wrong value (2147483647). I can't figure out where this value is coming from. Here is my code:

```
$myID = 5;
$loginTokenNew = time() * rand(3, 33) * $myID;
$_SESSION['loginToken'] = $loginTokenNew;

$mysqli = connectToDB();
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users SET token=? WHERE id=?') or die('Couldn\'t update user token');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $loginTokenNew, $myID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

The weird thing is that the session variable takes the right value, but the "token field" in the db keeps taking the value: 2147483647

Is my prepared statement wrong somehow or could it have something to do with my db?
the field "token" is a INT (255) field btw.

Comment: yes i have session_start(). And sessions on my pages is working fine.. it's only the database token that is set to the wrong value

Comment: Ok. It seems like [Sverri's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19166990/1415724) below make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2147483647` is the [largest number](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) a signed 32-bit (4-byte) `INT` can hold.

Change the field to a bigger type, such as `BIGINT` (or `BIGINT UNSIGNED` if the number is always positive), or to a string type, such as `VARCHAR`.